# Best practices for developing larger JavaScript applications

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ide, system-design, interface-design

Having a strong background in Java/C++ i wonder if it is possible to develop a somewhat larger JavaScript application without having to cut back on quality.

Any hints are appreciated regarding:

- Development Enviroment
- Debugging Techniques
- Unit Testing
- Profiling
- Instrumentation
- System Design
- Interface Design
- Code Design

I'm also curious how projects like [JavaScript PC Emulator](http://bellard.org/jslinux/) and [JavaScript Game Engine](http://impactjs.com/) handled those issues in case some of you know.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142250/how-to-write-high-quality-javascript

Comment: Most definitely use http://jetbrains.com/webstorm/ from JetBrains as for the IDE.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Development Environment**
Well, you need a web server (depends on server-side architecture) like Apache or IIS to simulate the AJAX communication.
Sometimes an editor for javascript is included in the editor of the server-side development language.

There's a interesting question about javascript IDEs:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209126/good-javascript-ide-with-jquery-support

---

**Debugging Techniques & Profiling**
Use built-in browser debugging and profiling tools like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/javascript).

You can also look at [this](http://www.gscottolson.com/blackbirdjs/) profiling tool.

---

**Unit Testing**
If jQuery is used I'd recommend http://docs.jquery.com/Qunit. In the development version of the javascrit application the javascript test files are loaded. When the application is published, the test files aren't loaded.

---

**Security**

- Validate and calculate everything on **server-side**
- Prevent XXS

---

- [How to make a secure game in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543881/how-to-make-a-secure-game-in-javascript)
- [Making AJAX calls secure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971826/making-ajax-calls-secure)

---

**Design**

> Application--------------------------------

- Application Components
- Custom Widgets

> Framework----------------------------------

- Base Widgets
- Base AJAX Communication
- UI Core (Helper Methods...)

The framework provides the base functions. For example a base framework is [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/). And on top of this framework the application is built. Of course you can create your own framework for your application. But when choosing jQuery for example, you mostly don't need to deal with cross-browser bugs, because jQuery makes that for you.

---

**Communication with Server:**
It's a good idea to provide a [RESTful Service](http://ajaxpatterns.org/RESTful_Service) for communicating. You also have to choose between JSON and XML. JSON is more lightweight than XML, so often JSON is elected.

---

**Design Patterns:** If the javascript application is really large, it's a good idea to implement design patterns like MVC or MVVM.

There are some MVC/MVVM frameworks outside for javascript ([knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) for example).

- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/javascript-mvc/
- [Flyweight pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-DE/scriptjunkie/hh273390.aspx)

**This is a really useful article about design patterns in javascript: http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/**

---

But at the end you have to decide yourself how your application should be structured etc. The Design Patterns can show you a good way - but every application is different and not every solution works for all problems.

And don't forget that performance is a big deal when using javascript. So compressing and combining  javascript files is a good idea: http://code.google.com/intl/de/speed/articles/. At this point [Lazy Loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) might help, too.

Comment: Thanks for your response... i'll look into it. Using eclipse & aptana as javascript ide looks very promising :).

Comment: "Validate and calculate everything on server-side" I know the concept but in this case i'm thinking more about writing a offline clientside application with probably less than 5% server side code. Do you got any thoughts on that? Thanks

Comment: Of course you can calculate things related to displaying etc at the client. But if you save data on the server, all the data should be validated at server-side before adding the data to the database for example. If invalid/dangerous data is loaded from the server when visiting the app again, you'll probably run into a problem.

Comment: This answer is currently outdated.

Answer (score 14):

I've participated in writing large JavaScript application with both [SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com) and [Cappuccino](http://www.cappuccino.org) and without any "Macroframework" at all. This is what I think:

First of all, all the same "good design" principles that you've acquired in your work with Java still apply: don't write Spaghetti code, encapsulate, separate concerns and use MVC.

Lots of people start writing a "web 2.0" or "web 3.0" (whatever that means) app, just add jQuery to it and go down a path of pain and misery, as their code becomes bigger and bigger and completely unmaintainable.

"Big" frameworks like Cappuccino or SproutCore help you to avoid doing that. Cappuccino is great for desktop-style apps while SproutCore has shifted focus in 2.0 to "web style" apps like New Twitter, while still giving you great ways to structure your apps and your code.

Now to your specific areas or interest:

### Development Enviroment

I personally use MacVim. I've heard good things about [Cloud9IDE](http://cloud9ide.com/), an in-browser IDE for JS development. For Cappuccino, you can use Apple's Xcode IDE, even to design the UIs (which is very cool).

Both Cappuccino and SproutCore apps can be tested right in the browser, without the need for a web server. If you do need to talk to a web server (which you probably will), [Ruby on Rails](http://www.rubyonrails.org/) or [node.js](http://nodejs.org) are commonly used to easily get a backend up and running.

### Debugging Techniques

Debugging is still sort of a sore spot when it comes to JavaScript development. The [Google Chrome developer tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/scripts-breakpoints.html) are the best out there at the moment. You can set breakpoints right in the browser and all sorts of neat things. It's the tool you'll want to use.

### Unit Testing

SproutCore uses QUnit, Cappuccino comes with OJUnit/OJSpec. Then there are projects like [JSDOM](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) and [env.js](http://www.envjs.com/) that let you simulate a browser on the server and give you an environment to run automated tests without a browser.

Also projects like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) are worth checking out.

### Profiling/Instrumentation

You can do [profiling with the Chrome Dev Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/profiles.html).
[YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/yslow/) is great for general web application profiling (including asset loading and the like).

### System Design

Use MVC from the get-go. Lots of people start with a small app and add some JavaScript here to read a value from a field and some more JavaScript there to update a label. They do that again. And again. And dinner is served: Spaghetti code. Use a framework like [SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com) or [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) to prevent that and to structure your code.

This is a [great tutorial for SproutCore](http://guides.sproutcore.com/getting_started.html), this is [one for backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html).

Same goes for Cappuccino, here a [tutorial I wrote about a year ago](http://www.springenwerk.com/2010/02/basic-cappuccino-tutorial.html). It's a little dated, but gives you the general idea. Here's [an up-to-date demo app](https://github.com/jfahrenkrug/CappuccinoCibImageSearch) I did for an article I wrote for MacTech magazine in May.

So structure your code just as you would in any other development environment. Maybe read [this book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748) or [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593272820), too. [These videos are also a great resource](http://yuiblog.com/crockford/).

### Interface Design

For Cappuccino you can use Apple's Xcode Interface Builder to graphically lay out your UI. For most other systems you'll design your UI with standard HTML and CSS.

If you want to develop for mobile, [you must read this article](http://jtaby.com/2011/07/01/the-next-generation-of-mobile-web-apps.html).

### Code Design

Refer to the books and videos I've mentioned above. And consult [this general coding style](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html). Naturally people disagree on some aspects of the style laid out on that page, but it's a good starting point.

JavaScript is an exciting environment to develop for and it has a very vibrant community! You should join the fun! I hope my opinions were helpful to you.

Comment: great response. i beg to differ regarding one point though - Firefox+Firebug is superior to Chrome dev tools. In terms of pure JS debugging, they are probably close but I would still give it to Firebug - especially when considering all the other features.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks! I do think that Firebug is a great tool. It sometimes gives you more detailed information than Chrome, esp when something goes wrong. In what areas do you think it's superior?

Comment: after you challenged me i went back to pull my argument together. it looks like chrome dev tools has changed significantly since last i used it a few months ago. i withdraw my claim!

Answer (score 10):

About the tools:

- **JSLint** is an online tool developed by Douglas Crockford at http://www.jslint.com/.
  It tells you why, even if the possibility is improbable, your code may break.
- **JSMin** is a one-file javascript minifier written in C. Compile it, put it in your $PATH, and
  use it to create build scripts for your app. Minified javascript is considered faster to
  load. Get it at http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html.
- Having a JS Read-Eval-Print Loop is always handy. The most downloaded one is [**node.js**](http://nodejs.org/), a REPL based on V8, the Chrome javascript engine. It lets you
  interactively test javascript snippets. It also functions as one of the most powerful web servers, through a witty event-loop system. You are encouraged to use it this way!
- A JS prompt is good, but you do need an outstanding **Web Inspector**. It provides generous debugging and better understanding of your code. In that field, both Google Chrome and Firebug are considered top-notch. The difference is, Google Chrome's is built-in. Right click > inspect, and you're done.
  But the best features in there can only be discovered [in this colorful cheatsheet](https://github.com/borismus/DevTools-Lab/raw/master/cheatsheet/chromedev-cheatsheet.png).
- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is an online tool to try out snippets too.
- @mathias is quite proud to maintain [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/), a collection of items 
  which test JS snippets and can tell, cross-browser, which algorithm is fastest.
- [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) is another really accurate tool to tell you if your website is fast, and how you can improve it, with witty advice.

As far as **IDEs** are concerned, there is no single development environment that is proved more effective. The best people in the field only use the text editor they fancy most (@phoboslab, the man behind ImpactJS, uses [KomodoEdit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit), for instance. Paul Irish uses TextMate, which is good, but Mac-only. A lot of people use Vim. Fabrice Bellard, the guy behind JSLinux, uses his own Emacs version, I think. This does not matter a single bit).

**Unit testing** is important, but that is never an issue. Javascript is powerful enough that you can build yourself a better-suited unit testing software in a couple of lines than anything out there. What does matter is that, thanks to node.js (the JS prompt that I recommend above), you can automate those tests by putting them in a *.js script file and launch all the testing with the single line: `$ node test.js`.

What *really* counts to be effective is to have the [mdn **javascript documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript) under your pillow, and the [html specification](http://developers.whatwg.org/) always open. Mind you, the version I point you to is not widely known, but it is by far the best out there! It even uses the cache manifest so that you can re-read the pages you have already downloaded, when you're offline! Let alone an outstanding search feature!

And now, since I really want that bounty, I'll give you one nifty page that lists **all the [documentation](http://platform.html5.org/)** that you will ever need to build a **web app**. It really is a jewel. It contains a link to all information you need. That is the index of all bibles out there.

In the end, the question that really targets what you are wondering is, can you do a huge app in javascript?
The answer is yes. Javascript does have what Crockford calls "bad parts", but using JSLint warns you against them. On the other hand, Javascript has powerful weapons:

- Closures: you can define a function inside another function, and it will have access to ouside variables, even after the outer function is done running.
- First-class functions: you can create arrays of functions, pass in functions as parameters to other functions, return a function from another function, all this for free!
- Object literals, array literals: this is the basis of JSON. It is very easy to use.
  All javascript engines now have a `JSON.parse(aString)` and a `JSON.stringify(anObject)` built-in object.
- Prototyping: objects can inherit from any variable you have previously defined.

This makes working efficient and easy. There are some specific patterns that you can use in Javascript. I'll let [Paul Irish enlighten you](http://paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/).

One last advice, when using javascript in the browser: never use `<script>/* some javascript here */</script>`. Always use `<script src="javascript-file.js"></script>`.

And a couple more links.

- http://my.opera.com/emoller/blog/2011/05/01/javascript-performance or how to not fear implementing ZIP in the browser.
- http://paperjs.org/features/ about how far we can go now. Editing precompiled javascript on the go!
- http://brendaneich.com/2011/05/mozillas-nodeconf-presentation/ about the future of javascript.

Comment: Thanks :). Although text editor sounds a bit nasty when aiming for hundreds of files. I would prefer something in the league of Eclipse and Visual Studio with code completion, refactoring, navigation shortcuts, beautification, tasklists, documentation templates and so on.

Answer (score 7):

You can check out Google's [Closure library and compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/). They write some pretty large Javascript apps too.

Answer (score 6):

You should look into alternatives to JavaScript that still allow you to deploy in a JavaScript like environment.

A lot of writing large apps is having a tool chain that make it easy for individuals and teams to get code working together without having to have everyone communicate with everyone else, an O(n**2) problem.

Things like [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) allow you to write in Java so if you have a team that is capable of coordinating development in Java or another statically typed application development language, they might find the transition to GWT much easier than to JavaScript.  GWT also provides solid core libraries, templating, in-java-IDE debugging, minimized code per-browser, and a whole lot of other goodies.

GWT also works with java unit testing facilities, namely [junit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JUnit.html) and many java teams are already experienced with integrating junit into continuous build systems and test dashboards.

Comment: What's your advice if the application is meant to be a Chrome/Firefox addon with rather much clientside logic communicating with different thirdparty services? Still GWT?

Comment: @milbollma, It depends on what the team knows.  If the team knows how to build large apps in python/ruby, then GWT is not a good idea.  If you have Java or C# people then I would tend to favor GWT.  Either way, it's probably not a bad idea to have your team try a small pilot project with a toolchain before committing entirely.

Comment: Apart from the team do you know a best fit (technical) if offline clientside functionality, browser addon integration (Traditional Browsers as well as GoogleTV and ChromeOS) and communication with multiple thirdparty services are the main concerns?

Comment: @milbollma, No I do not.  Sorry.  GWT does a lot of work to abstract away odd browsers.  I would ask on the GWT mailing list about support for specific GoogleTV and ChromeOS APIs.  I do know that GWT's JSNI ( http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html ) does allow access to any and all APIs available to JavaScript so you're not limited to the APIs that are available via Java APIs.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 4):

*Note that this post is more web focused, as that is where I primarily work*

**Development Environment**

If you prefer IDEs, JetBrains has a really good web editor [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) that makes working in javascript a lot easier. [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) is another good option. Otherwise text editors are always a great option (TextMate is my preference).

**Debugging Techniques**

Mentioned above, browser DOM tinkering tools like firebug are a must. You need to be able to declare and evaluate your code in the environment where it is being used without having to save and reload constantly.

Another point to mention here is [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/), which is strict validation of your javascript. This is equivalent to compiler time errors and can be invaluable when fixing issues in javascript.

**Unit Testing**

The best unit testing framework for javascript is [jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) (based off of rspec style tests). Some people do not like BDD style declarations, though most people that use TDD accept BDD is just TDD done right. Personally, I find the BDD style helps focus people towards what they are trying to test. It has extensive assertion support and a lot of work has been done to handle the asynchronous nature of javascript, without getting too dirty.

**Profiling/Instrumentation**

Most browsers have integrated development support. Both firefox and chrome are great here. Though the tooling doesn't provide great detail, they can easily be used to recognize that a slow point is in your server or in your client side code. With that information, deeper analysis would be needed, but it should be just work to track down and fix the issue.

This is definitely a space that is going to see a lot of growth outside of browsers with the growing popularity of [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/).

**Design (System/Code/Interface)**

Any major javascript application is going to run into all of the issues that any dynamically typed language will. Furthermore, javascript also has a very long history in which a lot of bad code was and is written everyday. Javascript does nothing to push you into the pit of success, hence books like, "Javascript, the good parts".

On the other hand, javascript has great support for OOP, as well as functional programming (functions are first class citizens in the language). Object literals are a beautiful combination of objects in the class sense and dictionaries in the structure sense. On top of this, there are some truly [unique features](http://blog.stannard.net.au/2011/01/07/10-interesting-javascript-features/) too the language and they can allow you to accomplish many powerful things.

With these considerations, you can apply any patterns you would use in other languages. There are numerous frameworks that take advantage of this. There is a great article that goes through many of the common frameworks for dependency management, code organization, templating, module communication, build process (including minification) and finally testing.

[Building Large-Scale jQuery Applications](http://addyosmani.com/blog/large-scale-jquery/)

Answer (score 3):

It's still possible to use Java like tools when developing with JS. The company that I work for has a 500K+ loc application, and we employ tools like Maven to deal with library dependencies. We also use Eclipse for JS development using the WTP plugin.

We use JS Test Driver for UnitTests and selenium for ATs. For degugging and profiling, we generally use Firebug and the IE debugger built into VS Web Express.

For code compilation, we use Google closure and a Java Servlet for serving JS during the development process, which is able to load the each JS file and it's dependencies in an order that ensures that class dependencies are available.

Answer (score 3):

Majority of your questions has already been answered, however, I'm very surprised that nobody mentioned [DynaTrace Ajax](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/) as profiling tool, since it's by far the best tool available on the market right now for in-browser JavaScript application profiling.

For debugging, you will have to rely on build-in browser debuggers (developer tools in Chrome/Safari, Developer toolbar in IE, Firebug in Firefox), but the most powerful debugging tool is still IE + Visual Studio, though not very comfortable at times.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://weblog.bocoup.com/the-strategy-pattern-in-javascript) may help in understanding **The Strategy Pattern in JavaScript**