# Securing Webservice called by ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, security, iis

i have built website with asp.net webservice where the user can register and login and make ads but the main issue that the webservice is not secured cause i can call it and pass parameters to it in the basic console of the google chrome i can execute webmethod and add user with any role i like without any credentials the code is

```
 $.ajax(
        {
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '/anywebservice.asmx/AddUser',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                FullName: $('#txtFullName').val(),
                BirthDate: "1/1/1900",
                GenderId: $("input:radio[name='rblGender']:checked").val(),
                CountryId: $("#ddlCountries").val(),
                Email: $('#txtEmail').val(),
                Mobile: $('#txtMobile').val(),
                RoleName: "Users",
                LoginName: $('#txtUserName').val(),
                Password: $('#txtPassword').val(),
                IsApproved: "true"
            }),
            beforeSend: function () {
                //$('.tableContent').block({ message: null });
                //$('.tableContent').spin(opts);
            },
            complete: function () {
                //$('.tableContent').unblock();
                //$('.tableContent').spin(false);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.d < 0) {
                    CustomAlert(data.d);
                }
                else {
                    CustomAlert(window.lang.translate("You have sucssesfully registered"));
                }

            }
        });
```

of course i know that i can create separated webmethod that does not take role name as parameter but this method is just example i have many methods that i am using for the clients but i need them to be secured not like this or i should separate the admin webservice from the client webservice and if so how can i secure both

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making AJAX calls secure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971826/making-ajax-calls-secure)

Answer (score 0):

Require authentication/authorization on any AJAX request you want to secure.

In your example, add 2 parameters: the `LoginName` and `Password` **of the user submitting the request**. Then perform authentication/authorization on the sever to ensure the user has rights to add a new user.  Return a 403 response if they are not authorized.